# Simple integral exercise: Need to understand the correction

Tags: integration

I am trying to understand an exercise ([Exercice And Correction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAoTw.jpg)) about integral.
I currently stuck on the last question (3). The problem is, first I do not understand the purpose of the formula in red, why it is important ?. Second, I do not understand how we can reach the primitive in blue, it seem that we completely skip the $cos(x)$ in $cos(x) \times \frac{1-sin^2(x)}{1-2sin(x)}$. I hope I am clear enough, please let me now if you need more details since the exercise is in french... Thank you!

Comment: They simply do the substitution $\sin x=u$. Neglect the rest.

Comment: IMHO the given result for 3) is false.

Comment: $\displaystyle \int_a^b \cos(x)f(\sin(x))\,dx=\int_{\sin(a)}^{\sin(b)}f(u)\,du$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\displaystyle \int_a^b \cos(x)f(\sin(x))\,dx=\int_{\sin(a)}^{\sin(b)}f(u)\,du$

$\displaystyle \frac{\cos^3 x}{1-2\sin x}=\frac{\cos x\times \cos^2 x}{1-2\sin x}=\frac{\cos x\times (1-\sin ^2 x)}{1-2\sin x}$ then apply formula above.

NB: the change for variable $u=\sin x$ has been performed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, look like the correction is strange... However, if someone does understand it, I'll be glad to have an explanation!

Comment: Manzerbredes: la correction n'est pas qu'étrange. le résultat pour l'intégrale 3 est faux voir: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+cos%28x%29%5E3%2F%281-2*sin%28x%29%29%2Cx%3D-pi%2F6%2C0 (je ne me souviens plus comment on poste un lien correctement dans un commentaire désolé)

Comment: Ok thank you, so I'll mark it as solved!